# Google Map place API repeats listing credits on map

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-places

I am trying to integrate Google Place API into my application which I have successfully done it. However, I am not so sure why there is a repeated listing credit at the bottom left of the map.

My code to place those google place markers is as follows. To help you guys better understand the problem, a screen shot have been provided after the code snippet.

```
  var request = {
        location: latlng,
        radius: '500',
        types['bank','cafe','bus_station','gym','beauty_salon','convenience_store','health','school','store',
        'gym','hair_care','school','police','pet_store','parking','pharmacy','dentist','church','bus_stop']
    };
   service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
    service.nearbySearch(request, callback);
```

[image]

I am pretty sure that the culprit is the above code snippet. Help is appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I guess the missing colon after `types` does not occur in the original code? If yes: please provide more code or a fiddle, for me there is nothing wrong with the code above: http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/SSXkD/

Comment: Hi Dr. Molle, Thanks for the quick reply and sorry for my late reply. I have not give adequate code which I realize later. You are right, the above code does not have anything wrong. I foolishly have the above snippet wrapped in a for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Map Api have not meant the following snippet to be in a for loop.

```
  service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
    service.nearbySearch(request, callback);
```

When called for multiple times, you will get a repeated credit line on the map.